# How to use a word to express "Number of volunteers I want to recruit" for a volunteer program

Tags: word-request

I'am writing an online announcement for volunteer programs. On webpage, the program is described as following format:

> 1. Program Name: xxx
> 2. Program Description: xxx
> 3. Begin date: xxx
> 4. [word-request-here] -> Number of positions provided for volunteers to apply for /or/ Number of volunteers I want to recruit in this program

How to use a few words to decribe 4th column ?

Comment: "Volunteers required:" or "No of volunteers required". Normally we say "start date" rather than "begin date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to imply.

To state it as fact:

> Positions Available: 8

To suggest a limit on participation:

> Maximum Volunteers Allowed: 6

For ambiguity:

> Openings: 10

To emphasize teamwork:

> Team Members: 7

Answer (score 0):

*Volunteers Needed*

*Num of Volunteers Needed*

*Volunteer Positions*

-

Instead of *X Needed*, you could have *Requested*. Judging from OP's question it's a request for volunteers.

John's answer is usable too, if it's obvious from context it's a volunteer application. I don't know who downvoted it. You could even use *Volunteers* if it's a volunteer request.

Comment: Downvotes do not necessarily imply incorrectness. The downvote says "This answer is not useful". There was no explanation provided, and so is a low quality answer.